# Find the eigenvectors of the given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
i & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & i\\
0&i&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues are i and -i where $i=(-1)^{1/2}$. The eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue i calculated by Mathematica are $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$. However, I want to ask if I can replace $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$ with $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ and declare $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ as the two eigenvectors since both of these vectors satisfy the equation $Ax=i x$ and form a linearly independent set.

Comment: Indeed, you can.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!, you can add two eigenvectors, since  the Eigenspace is a subspace.

Indeed, the Eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $i$ is, $E_i=\{x : (A-iI)x=0\}$ where $x=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3
\end{pmatrix}^T
$

Solving $(A-iI)x=0$, we get $x_2=x_3$

So, $$E_i=\Bigg\{x_1 \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}+x_2 \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}: x_1,x_2 \in F \Bigg\} $$

By choosing $x_1=x_2=1$, you get the mentioned vector of $1$'s !

Comment: So can I use {1,1,1} and {0,1,1} as the 2 eigenvectors of the matrix for eigenvalue i?